Named argument in Symfony DI services fails to load class
I have a class which I cannot edit with the following constructor:
    /**
     * @param int|null $maxBodyLength
     * @param string   $binaryDetectionRegex By default, this is all non-printable ASCII characters and <DEL> except for \t, \r, \n
     */
    public function __construct($maxBodyLength = 1000, string $binaryDetectionRegex = '/([\x00-\x09\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F])/')
    {
        $this->maxBodyLength = $maxBodyLength;
        $this->binaryDetectionRegex = $binaryDetectionRegex;
    }


Using services.xml I want to set maxBodyLength to null. Doing this works:
    <service id="meteor.api_logger.formatter" class="Http\Message\Formatter\FullHttpMessageFormatter">
        <argument>null</argument>
    </service>

But when I use a named parameter as preferred I get an error:
    <service id="meteor.api_logger.formatter" class="Http\Message\Formatter\FullHttpMessageFormatter">
        <argument key="$maxBodyLength">null</argument>
    </service>

In AbstractRecursivePass.php line 174:

  Invalid service "meteor.api_logger.formatter": class "Http\Message\Formatter\FullHttpMessageFormatter" does not exist.


Already tried:

Also passing the other argument in services.xml
Removing $ from the key
Using 0 instead of null
Using <argument key="$maxBodyLength"/>

All gave the same error. How to use named arguments to pass value null?

"Class does not exist" does not look related to which argument you use? Why do you need to use a named parameter here anyways? As far as I read the documentation, that's not possible after all

@NicoHaase It is used here in the docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#choose-a-specific-service And it's necessary for coding best practices (I guess). And it seems it's kinda related because the error is directly caused/solved by removing the line with the argument.

Have you tried using debug:container to make sure you've got the right id for the service you're trying to modify the default arguments for? The Symfony docs on How to Debug the Service Container & List Services might be helpful. You can also inspect the arguments available for a specific service with the --show-arguments option.
